# What are the thousands of lines in error in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not sure what it means when a python error prints `line 1500 in __getitem__` or `line 1913, in _getitem_axis` - where are these lines from?

For example,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    us = df.loc['origin' == 'US']
  File "script.py", line 1500, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "script.py", line 1913, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "script.py", line 141, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "script.py", line 3575, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "script.py", line 2604, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "script.py", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "script.py", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "script.py", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: False
```

*P.S. Appreciate if you could use human language or explain via analogy/example.*

Comment: The error `File "script.py", line 1500` means line number 1500 in the file `script.py`. The name of the function is just additional information to help you debug.

Comment: This is called a "backtrace" or (as above) "traceback". Use these as keywords for your research.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I only have a few lines in the code itself. Where is the file? How is it created?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think it's pretty clear that they have a fundamental misunderstanding of how programs like this work. A new programmer may write only 10 lines of code and expect (naively, but if they are new to programming, this is not too unexpected) only their code to be running. If they get all of this error output from files that aren't their own and lines they've never seen before,, they might be confused where that code came from. They don't understand built-in type things or standard libraries that are implicitly included in the functionality of the language.

Comment: "I only have a few lines in the code itself. Where is the file?" Did you save your code into a file? Is it named `script.py`? Then that is the file, and it is indeed that long. Or perhaps did someone else give you a `script.py` file, and you wrote something like `import script`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a stack trace. It shows not just where the actual error occurred directly, but also what the program was doing while it occurred.

- The code `df.loc['origin' == 'US']` (on line 6) is at the top of the trace, meaning it's the root cause, but this by itself is not an error. This will evaluate `'origin' == 'US'` to `False`, since this is a simple string comparison and the strings aren't equal, and then it will evaluate `df.loc[False]`.
- Evaluating this requires looking up the key `False` in the object `df.loc`. This calls the `__getitem__` method, which is called whenever you access a key using the syntax `a[b]`.
- The `__getitem__` method has a line `return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)` calling a method named `_getitem_axis`. This is on line 1500 of the file.
- The `_getitem_axis` method has a line `return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)`, calling a method `_get_label`. This is line 1913 of the file.
- ...and so on...
- Finally, the method `pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type` checks the type of the key. The key is `False`, which is of type `bool`. Presumably, this is not a valid type for the lookup you were doing, so the `_check_type` method raises a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 6):

Those functions are part of the Python built-in support; many of the routines are long, or are one function in a long module.  The dots are part of the naming convention: packages, modules, submodules, ... function.  For instance

```
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
```

`get_loc` is a basic location retrieval function in the PANDAS data frame package.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms and "human language", python is a high-level programming language. This means that it hides a lot from the programmer when translating English words typed into a console to bits that the machine takes as instruction. Take simple multiplication. You might take it for granted that the asterisk `*` symbol in `2 * 2` means multiply, but your computer can not and does not take this for granted. No, there must be a file somewhere that defines the use of the ASCII symbol `*` in your code, and, when encountered, how to multiply two numbers together (or for that matter, how to do things like `2 * 'string'`). All these lower level definitions are lying somewhere in your python install on your machine. When you type in instructions as English words, a compiler must parse it line-by-line, go rooting around the python install for all these lower level definitions, and, based on these definitions, convert your python to stuff the computer can actually work with. In doing this intensive process, many different functions and definitions, across possibly multiple files and installed libraries, may be encountered for a very simple python statement. If, during this process, an issue is encountered where the compiler does not know how to proceed, an error is thrown. The error that is thrown can look complex, but, as others have described, it contains the entire trace as to what was being looked at by the compiler at the very moment the error was discovered. This can be a huge help when debugging your program (or maybe even finding a bug in a library you had to import, etc).

Hope this helps!